# Extract sentence from lines of text

Tags: r, string, text

I have multiple sentences that are structured like the below:

```
text <- "09/11/2017\n                        Janssen noted September 11, 2017 that no further development planned."
```

I am aiming to extract everything but the white space and the "mm/dd/yyyy\n . 
So far I am doing this:

```
text <-  substring(text, 20, last=100)

> text
[1] "                Janssen noted September 11, 2017 that no further development plan"
```

The output is kind of close except I wish to ignore the white space before the text and keep the white space between each word.

In my real life example:

```
> nchar <- nchar(df$text, type = "chars", allowNA = TRUE, keepNA = NA) # Count characters
> max(nchar,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 81
```

my maximum text is 81 long.... So I picked a start that purposely misses the date and then make the last longer than my maximum.

Not perfect way of doing it. 
Can I do a length(nchar) for the last?

Anyways, looking for a better solution to the above.

Desire output:

```
"Janssen noted September 11, 2017 that no further development planned."
```

Comment: `sub("^[[:digit:][:space:][:blank:]/]+", "", text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another one that works:

`gsub("^[\\W\\d+]+(.*)","\\1",text, perl=TRUE)`

`^` start at the beginning of the string

`\\W` match a non-word character
`\\d+` match one or more numbers

Put those two in brackets which means match either one of those.

`+` match either of the above pronouns more than once

`(.*)` match everything that comes after the initial white space and digits, and capture it in group 1.

We return the group with `\\1`

Comment: Which part ignores the dates and white space?

Comment: @AndrewBannerman This part does `^[\\W\\d+]+` basically this means match "non-word" characters (so slashes, white-space, punctuation, your `\n` line break, etc.) or numbers, until you hit an actual word character (specified by the second part `([a-zA-Z].*)`.

Comment: @AndrewBannerman and I just made a little update, you don't even need the `[a-zA-Z]` part, you can just use `gsub("^[\\W\\d+]+(.*)","\\1",text, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
gsub("\\d+/\\d+/\\d+\\n\\s+(.+)$", "\\1", text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you started, you can use the `trimws` function to remove the leading whitespace.

```
text <-  substring(text, 20, 1000000L) # what you did first
trimws(text, which = "left") # remove the leading whitespace
```